# WebWorker with Backbone : "define is not defined"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, web-worker

I've implemented a webworker inside a web-page that uses backbone. I want to start the webworker in my index.html file as soon as the web page begins to load. 
Here's my index.html's javascript code:

```
var w;
startWorker();
function startWorker() {
    alert("new worker");
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        alert("new worker");
        if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
            alert("new worker");
            w = new Worker("js/models/worker_prefetch_starred.js");
        }
        w.onmessage = function(event) {
            // Comunication WebWorker <-> Webapp
        };
    }   
}
```

As you can se I'm only creating the worker and works fine.
Here's my worker_prefetch_starred.js webworker's javascript code:

```
    define(["underscore", "backbone" ],
    function ($, _) { 
        require('collections/folder_items').starred_items_fetched().then(function(starred_items) {
        _.each(starred_items, function(item) {   
            var linked_item = item.get("item");
            linked_item.isOnWebsql(linked_item);
        });
    });
 });
```

When I execute the code it throws me : `define is not defined`
What should I do?

Comment: Have you include the script tag to refer [require.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.8/require.js)? It is the one which defines variable `define`.

Answer (score 0):

You should include

```
importScripts('require.js');
```

in worker_prefetch_starred.js file.